# Ignoring some key,value pairs before saving dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I am new in Python (2 weeks) and got stucked in a issue.
I have this growing dictionary:

```
dict1={"some_large_key1":"value1","some_large_key2":"value2",........,"some_large_key1000":"value1000"}
```

Issue 1: I want to create a csv file,in which i don't want to include some of the key,value pairs.
--> 1 possible solution is to make a list of keys and ignore the entire list.

```
list1=["some_large_key1","some_large_key2","some_large_key3"]
for key,value in dict1:
    if key not in list1:         #something like this
        #do something
    else:
        #do something
```

Issue 2: I don't want to give such a large key name, instead i can just give :

```
list1=["key1","key2",...]
```

Is it a right approach or should i think something else ?

Comment: I would recommend using a set instead of a list since the `in` operator is constant in a set. But, yea, you'll definitely need that if statement to filter out values you don't want to print.

Comment: Can you elaborate the relationship between your "some_large_key1" and "key1"? Do you use some functions to reduce "some_large_key1" to "key1" or just literally ignore the first few characters?

Comment: @dazedconfused : So i have this key name: "some_large_key1". Instead of using this larger name, i want to make it simple by just passing "key1" in ignore list. So while iterating the dict, if i found any key containing "key1" like "blah_blah_key1", i will simply ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between your "some_large_key1" and "key1" is not very clear; however, I think you can do something like:

```
original_dict = {
    "some_large_key1": "value1", 
    "some_large_key2": "value2", 
    ......, 
    "some_large_key1000": "value1000"
}
to_ignore = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', ...]
filtered_dict = {key: value for (key, value) in original_dict.items() if key.rsplit('_', 1)[-1] not in to_ignore}
```

What `key.rsplit('_', 1)[-1]` does is that it removes the `some_large_` prefix; you can replace this part with the function which transfer your long key names into shorter ones.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. This is my first question in stackoverflow. I am trying to improve. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a list of keys you want to ignore.

```
dict1={"some_large_key1":"value1","some_large_key2":"value2","some_large_key3":"value3"}
ignore_list=['key1', 'key2']
new_dict = {}
for key in dict1:
    if not any(x in key for x in ignore_list):
        key_list=[key]
        value_list=[dict1[key]]
        #make a new dict from above 2 lists  (This will exclude ignore key,value pair)
        for i in range(len(key_list)):
            new_dict[key_list[i]] = value_list[i]
print new_dict
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'some_new_key3':'value3'}  #Note that key1,key2 is ignored in this output dictionary.
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use `range(len(key_list))`; as the Python core developer Raymond Hettinger [said](https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-python-by-raymond-hettinger-1) in PyCon 2013, _Whenever you find yourself manipulating indices in a collection, you're probably doing it wrong._

Comment: @dazedconfused : I appreciate your comment. Your answer is much cleaner and easy to understand. I learned something so +1 on your answer.